# Convert a collection of numbers as string to numbers

Tags: php

If I have a string as : `10 20 3 4 15 6`

How can I convert it to individual numbers and store it in a array?

Comment: `$array = explode(" ", "10 20 3 4 15 6");` like that?

Comment: You can also use `array_map('intval', $array);` to convert string numbers to integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is very clever when dealing with types of variables. You don't need it to be an integer, it can be a string of numbers, and PHP would still treat it as integers when performing operations on them.

If you want to have each element be the numbers separated by spaces, you simply do

```
$array = explode(" ", "10 20 3 4 15 6");
```

The output of `$array` would then be

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 15
    [6] => 6
)
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/O33uI)

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "10 20 3 4 15 6";
$arr = str_split($str); 

$intArr = array_map('intval', $arr);
```

Might be a better way of doing it but the above should do the work.

Comment: That loop isn't needed. You can use just `array_map('intval', $arr);`

Comment: @Adam Made the change. :) Thanks Adam.